# how to add remove/delete button after upload on swfupload

Tags: php, javascript, upload, swfupload

i'm new here

images > http://cl.ly/3g070L1i3n2U1K2g322I

how to delete images (per images) after successfully upload in swfupload ?
can anyone give me some example ?

i got upload code from this tutorial -> http://webdeveloperplus.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload-with-progress-bar-using-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

`enter code here`Consider JQuery hide(). It does not only hide but virtually removes the component, which means if you have stuff positioned in relative mode right under for example, this content will move up.

In the html :

```
<button type="button" id="mybutton">Hello</button>
```

Just place your JQuery like that, for example. After click the button disappears :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function($){
  $('#mybutton').click() { $('#mybutton').hide(); });
});
</script>
```

Comment: thankyou for the response jerome, but that is not what i meant :(

Comment: i mean, how to add remove button below the picture , and remove the files after successfully upload

i got this code from here -> http://webdeveloperplus.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload-with-progress-bar-using-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   .bind('uploadSuccess', function(event, file, serverData){ 
        var item=$('#log li#'+file.id); 
        item.find('div.progress').css('width', '100%'); 
        item.find('span.progressvalue').text('100%'); 
        var pathtofile='<a href="uploads/'+file.name+'" target="_blank" >view &raquo;</a>'; 
        item.addClass('success').find('p.status').html('Done!!! | '+pathtofile); 
        item.remove();//to delete item from Q
    })
```

this may helps you